# Prompt to replace file while saving

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Below is what I'm trying to do -

1. Copy data from an existing workbook and paste as text to existing word file saved on local drive
2. Save that file using predefined text + value defined in excel cell + today's date
3. It all works fine but only problem I'm facing is, I want it to give me a prompt if file name already exists such that I could take an informed decision whether or not to replace it with existing one. But it doesn't do that. It just overwrites the existing one.

**Code**

```
Sub GenerateLabelandInvoice()
    'Open an existing Word Document from Excel
    Dim objWord As Object

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "D:\path name \ file name.docx"
    Range("L19:L29").Copy
    With objWord
        .Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

        objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="D:\path name\" & _
        "Address Label & Invoice - " & Range("L23").Value & " " & _
        Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".docx", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False

        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the filename in a variable and then using `DIR` test if the file exists.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim Ret As Variant

NewFileName = "D:\path name\" & "Address Label & Invoice - " & _
              Range("L23").Value & " " & _
              Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".docx"

If Dir(NewFileName) <> "" Then
    Ret = MsgBox("File exists. Would you like to replace", vbOKCancel)

    If Ret = vbOK Then
        objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    End If
Else
    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
End If
```

Comment: Hi Sid, thank you for lightning fast response. Should I copy this code before obj.activedocument.saveas code line.....

Comment: You may have to refresh the page. I had made some edits

Comment: Awesome!! works perfectly fine. But my intent was little different. I wanted that 'window pop up' that asks you to either replace file, cancel or compare info for both files. Is it possible? There might be times, when I would like to keep both the files and not overwrite. If not, I think, this code works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: You can get that option when you copy over the file and not when you try to overwrite it.

Comment: We can achieve that by saving the file to a temp directory and then try to copy over to get that :)

Comment: Understood, I'll work on that. Thank you so much Siddarth. Love from Gurgaon :-)

Comment: I was testing the new code which does exactly what you want... :D

Comment: Yup, i'm using exactly what you provided above. Works like a charm. Just changed the message in msgbox :D lol